# Problem with storing database queries values in array

Tags: 7, database, theming

I have a simple table with four field  email,title,url & status

status can be '0' or '1'

There can be multiple values with status '1'. I want to store the all datas from the table with status '1'  in array so i can output it later.

```
$values = db_query('select email,title,url from {example_table} where status= :one', array(':one' => '1'))->fetchAssoc();
```

The above array only stores one record in $values array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetchAssoc()` is only supposed to return a single result.

You're probably looking for [`Statement::fetchAllAssoc()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Database!Statement.php/function/Statement%3A%3AfetchAllAssoc/8)

> Returns the result set as an associative array keyed by the given field.